# Custom modification in generated files

Tags: jhipster

I'm searching for the correct way to modify as i wish the generated file that are create when running jhipster entity.
Let's take an example, i have generate a Foo entity, this have create some files like FooQueryService etc and if i want to adapt some of the queryService request. Each time i have to update an entity that is linked to Foo or Foo itself it's erasing all the custom change.
I know i can use git after regenerate entity but there is many file that are update and i was searching if there was not a better way?

Thanks in advance

To reproduce the behavior, just need to modify a auto generated file after jhipster entity command and try to rerun the command again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [JHipster Blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/) to customize templates for your own needs. If you just need to do it for a single project, you can use the local blueprint feature.

Comment: Thanks i will look at this. But i think i need to understand the side by side approach also. Especially for interface like the Mapper that are create by Jhipster. Because i can do the side by side on class with extend but with interface Mapper it's quite complex.